# Pythonic Way to Execute Action at a Threshold Value

Tags: python

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this but maybe I'm overlooking something.

Say I have a threshold value of 2.  I want to do an action as soon as a value exceeds 2.

If the subsequent value is also greater than or equal to 2 I don't want to do the action.

The only way I can figure out how to do this is to compare to the previous value which strikes me as clugy and not pythonic.

So:  I have a series:

```
series = [1.99, 1.88, 2.21, 2.32, 2.42, ....]
```

So at `series[2]` I want to do something because I've exceeded the threshold of 2.0.  But I don't want to do the same thing afterward.  Exceeding 2.0 triggers an action but does not repeat with subsequent values greater than 2.0

The only way I can think of doing this is comparing to the previous value:

Thus:

```
for i in range(length(series):

    if series[i] > 2.0 and series[i-1] <= 2.0:

        do something
```

This will work but just seems like bad programming.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Guidance please.

Comment: There is nothing cludgy or bad about this approach.

Comment: You can also use `itertools.groupby`: `groupby(series, lambda k: k > 2.0)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Could you describe further?

Comment: @Windstorm1981 I'll write answer

Comment: If `series[0]` is greater than 2.0, would you execute the action?

Comment: @ZecongHu only the first instance each time the threshold is crossed.  andrejKesely 's answer captures what I'm trying to do in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, here is one possible solution with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

series = [1.99, 1.88, 2.21, 2.32, 2.42, 1.0, 2.1]

def action(value):
    print('Action trigerred at value {}'.format(value))

for condition, g in groupby(series, lambda k: k > 2.0):
    if condition:
        action(next(g))
```

Prints:

```
Action trigerred at value 2.21
Action trigerred at value 2.1
```

Comment: I have looked at the documentation and I'm not completely clear on how `itertools.groupby` is working.  Can you explain a little more please?  From what I can tell, if the values in `series` are not sorted (as these aren't), the function identifies each `k>2` it finds as a new group when it exceeds the threshold and assigns the first value if there are several consecutive `k>2` values?

Comment: @Windstorm1981 The `itertools.groupby` in this case groups the `series` list into groups `[1.99, 1.88]`, `[2.21, 2.32, 2.42]`, `[1.0]` and  `[2.1]` based on `k > 2`. The `condition` is set to `False`, `True`, `False` and `True` respectively. Try to put `print(condition, [*g])` debug print instead of the `if` condition insde the for loop to see how `groupby` works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a state indicator to know if you are already now above threshold after being below previously. This would allow you to proceed without using indexes (which are not very Pythonic):

```
series    = [1,1,3,3,1,5,1,8,3,4,1]
threshold = 2.0
below     = True
for value in series:
    nowAbove = value > threshold
    if below and nowAbove:
        # do something
        print(value)
    below = not nowAbove

# 3
# 5
# 8
```

If you're doing this kind of loops often, you may want to consider creating a special iterator that will only return values where the action should be triggered (i.e. on the threshold triggering breaks):

```
def breaks(iterable,condition,state=False):
    for value in iterable:
        if condition(value) == state: continue
        state = not state
        if state: yield value

series    = [1,1,3,3,1,5,1,8,3,4,1]
threshold = lambda v: v > 2.0
for value in breaks(series,threshold):
    # do something (only values to process will be returned)
    print(value)
```

*The state parameter of the breaks() function allows you to decide if the first entry in the series is to be considered a break (e.g. when continuing from the last state of a previous series)*

Comment: This will not work.  If there are multiple movements across the threshold this will only pick up the first one.  Not all of them for the series.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I though you only wanted to trigger the action on the first break but it is actually on every break from below to above threshold.  Fixed it now.